# Decimal number regular expression, where only one digit after decimal

Tags: regex

How can I update my expression to allow only tenth decimal

```
    <form:input path="mark" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')
```

Like expected inputs

```
1.2   12456.5  565.5  45 458
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `toFixed()`

```js
var number = 1.2345
console.log(number.toFixed(1))
```

Or, if you really want regex, the following works. It matches any number of digits, followed by a decimal, then another digit, then captures any digits after that.

```js
var regex = /(\d+\.\d)(\d+)/
var one = "1.25"
var two = "1.2"
var three = "1"
var four = "12.25435345"
console.log(one.replace(regex, '$1'))
console.log(two.replace(regex, '$1'))
console.log(three.replace(regex, '$1'))
console.log(four.replace(regex, '$1'))
```

Comment: That didn't work with the oninput attribute, also it's allowing the alpha character

Comment: One thing about toFixed is that it rounds, not sure if that's desirable in this case.

Comment: You have to escape the dot in the regex to match it literally. Did you test your regex with `12456.5`? `var five = "12456.5"; console.log(five.replace(regex, '$1'));`

Answer (score 1):

This should match decimal number upto only one digit after decimal point

```
/([0-9]+(\.\d)?)/g
```

```js
var number = "1.2345"
var number2 = "45"
var number3 = "1.0"
console.log(number.match(/([0-9]+(\.\d)?)/g)[0])
console.log(number2.match(/([0-9]+(\.\d)?)/g)[0])
console.log(number3.match(/([0-9]+(\.\d)?)/g)[0])
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAu76p/1)

Comment: Your only capture group would only return the first number after a decimal so not sure how this would work to replace.